# Populate password on the login page using MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, passwords, viewdata

I am implementing single sign on and i have the login name and password from the parent site and would like to insert this values in the login and password field of the child site. How can i do this in C#, MVC. as of now i am able to populate the login name using viewdata but i m unable to populate the password.

Comment: That's because that is a big security risk that you're going to want to avoid.

Comment: Agreed that's not a valid solution for your problem, you should document yourself more about single sign-on, or better use a network tracer to see how popular website do this (msn passport, openid, google).

Comment: thanks for ur help guys.. I was trying to use this workaround as I was not able to pass parameters while calling the actionresult method. is there anyway that i can pass parameters to action result method. I have a method that takes care of the login i just want to pass the username acquired from the parent site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not single sign on. That is multiple sign-on with a giant security hole.

What you are looking for is federated identity. In this model, a trusted identity provider supplies the identity of the user to each site. Stack Overflow, for example, trusts Google (and other sites) to provide user identity. So instead of having a password system built-in to Stack Overflow, SO as a means of just asking Google who you are.

One popular way to do this is [OpenID](http://openid.net/). Another way to do it, which is useful if you are using corporate security such as a Windows domain, is [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx).